# Lift Authentication

Tags: scala, lift

I want to create an authentication route for my Lift Application.

1. Create a route, for instance `www.myapp.com/user/login`
2. I am not using Lift forms/templating. The forms are rendered in JS.
3. Send a post request with email and password.
4. Call Lift authentication when that POST request is received.
5. Use the `Users.login(email, password)` method to validate the credentials.

**Q:**
How do I tell Lift to authenticate the credentials incoming via `/user/login`?

Comment: Are you looking to access `/user/login`? Can you confirm that you defined the page in your `Sitemap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is overly simplistic, but something like this will allow you to create a url that you can post to. The JSON extraction is not very safe, but should give you an idea of how this might work.

#### In Boot.scala

```
LiftRules.dispatch.append(new RestHelper{
  serve {
    case JsonPost("user" :: "login" :: Nil, (json, _)) =>
      //extract JSON from json object to get username and password
      val userEmail:String = (json \ "username").extract[String]
      val password = (json \ "password").extract[String]
      User.login(userEmail, password) match {
        case Full(r) =>
          User.current(true)
          InMemoryResponse(Array(), Nil, Nil, 200)
        case _ => ForbiddenResponse
      }
  }
})
```

#### In User.scala

```
object User {
  object loggedIn extends SessionVar[Boolean](false)
}
```

Then you can use `if(User.loggedIn.get){ ... }` to test if the user is logged in anywhere. This will work for anything added to the stateful dispatch, if you use `LiftRules.statelessDispatch` the session will not exist.

Comment: The lift mechanism is probably not the best idea. I believe `httpAuthProtectedResource` is pretty much designed to use HttpAuthentication, and while you could probably hack something together to make it work, It's probably easier to perform the check manually, or roll your own - using one of lift's constructs like: `LiftRules.earlyInStateful` to check if the request matches the pattern of a URL you want protected.

Comment: Without some severe hacking (which would be more complicated than doing it from scratch), there really is no easy way to do that. The easiest thing I can think of would be to accept the POST data and then use a `RedirectResponse` to send the client to the url in the form of `http://username:password@example.com` which will make the browser authenticate with those credentials. `JAAS` was developed as part of the JEE spec to provide a standardized framework which gets at what you are looking to do, but it is not trivial to implement and Lift does not natively support it.

Comment: I put together an example repository which should help you get started: https://github.com/jcern/lift_session_auth . It should be pretty functional and can be adapted to your case. You can use roles and has a similar construct to the Lift http auth version. You'll see `LiftRules.earlyStateful` which is used to protect urls from Sitemap entries. There is also the `myGuard guard` which can be prefixed to any RestHelper and used to guard against the content. Required roles go in the `authenticates` method. Everything could be named better, but that should get you started on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

I created a quick working example which you can checkout on github. It uses the code you provided, so hopefully it will be pretty straightforward. You can take a look here: https://github.com/jcern/lift_httpauth

But, essentially to add the code to the sitemap, you'd just need to add the following to `Boot.scala`:

```
Menu("Login Required") / "user" / "login"
```

And make sure there is a `user/login.html` in your webapp root.

Comment: I am kind of confused about what you are looking to do. In the example you provided, you are going to be protecting the url `/user/login` by restricting it to users with the `user` role. `/user/login` can either be defined in the sitemap, or as a `RestHelper` appended to `LiftRules.dispatch`. But, either way, unless there is a `LiftResponse` attached the url, you will get a 404.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use HTTP authentication? Since HTTP authentication is done via headers, `WWW-Authenticate` (request) and `Authorized` (response) - to the best of my knowledge there is no way to make the browser send the `Authorized` header via a POST. The more typical usage would be to post credentials, and on success set a flag in the session that the user is logged in.