# example for user authentication in scala lift framework

Tags: scala, lift

Hi I am new to Lift framework.

I want to know how i can do user authentication like we used to do in java servlet, where we used to check whether user has logged in or redirect to login page.

How can i do similar thing in lift framework?

Following is my sample code in servlet filter, i want a equivalent in lift framework.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //This filter checks whether user has logged in if not redirect to him to single sign on page. 
        //If user has logged in already then we could get his information using Agent API

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        Agent agent = new Agent(inputStream);
        String encodedSiteUrl = getUrl(request);
        request.getSession(true);

        Map<String,String> userInfo = agent.readToken(request); 

        if (userInfo != null) { //Check if used has logged in, if yes then get his id and save it in session
                String userid = (String)userInfo.get(Agent.TOKEN_SUBJECT);
                logger.info("Login Userid:" + userid);
                request.getSession().setAttribute("Username", userid);

         } else {//if user did not login the redirect to Single sign on page
                response.sendRedirect(ssoRediretURL + encodedSiteUrl);
         }

}
```

Comment: describe a little more, actually your questions looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640124/lift-authentication

Comment: http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-9.html#sub:HTTP-Authentication

Comment: There is no reason you can't use this filter as is - since Lift itself gets instantiated as a Filter.  However, for deeper integration into Lift/Scala - you'd need to provide more information on what the libraries you are using are and what doesn't work, what you are trying to protect, etc...